# How to differentiate new and previous notifications

Tags: api, swift3, notifications

I have an API that returns notifications if any activity in account. I am working first time with notifications. I am displaying these notifications in to UITableView. If user clicks on any notification from the table it redirects to the referral view and delete that notification from the Table list.

Now what I want is, if user leave the notification view with for example 4 notification listed and if 2 new notifications are added to the API then those 2 should have grey background colour and other 4 should have white background colour when user returns to the notificationView.

It is all coming from same API so I am very confuse how to accomplish this result. Its kind of Facebook notifications you can say. Do I need to make any changes to API side which can indicate me if any new notifications are added or is there anything else I am missing ? I know there is push notifications available but I am not using it here. Will it solve the issue if I use it? I am very confused. Please, any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Update: Here is my code :

```
struct UserNotification {

    let id : Int?
    let timeStamp : String?
    let message : String?

    init(json:[String:Any]) {
        self.id = (json["Id"] as? Int)
        self.timeStamp = (json["TimeStamp"] as? String)
        self.message = (json["Message"] as? String)
    }
}

var notificationsArray : [UserNotification] = []

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.FetchNotifications()
}

func FetchNotifications(){


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonUrlString!) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String:Any]] {

                    self.notificationsArray.removeAll()
                    for notifications in jsonData {
                        let details = UserNotification(json: notifications)
                        self.notificationsArray.append(details)
                    } 
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            if (response as? HTTPURLResponse) != nil  {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.notificationTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let Cell = self.notificationTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomNotificationCell
//        Cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)

    let temp = notificationsArray[indexPath.item]
    // Setting id, time and message to labels 

}
```

Comment: how about keeping a list of opened notifications and comparing to that list when generating/updating the UI of the cells

also.... does the API support such call "notification has been read"

Comment: Thanks Andrei! I was thinking something similar but couldn't worked or may be I was doing it wrong way. Let me update the question with my code. Please have a look. And No API doesn't support "Read/Unread" Call. I was thinking to add if there isn't anything else I could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since there is no API to support this, you cannot have this info cross device / multiscreen (if a user will open the notification in one device you will not be able to tell this this on another device without some other form communicating).

**Need to save the info for a future app session**

You can use `UserDefaults.standard` to save the state for a future session on the same device. 
Create a `notificationsStatus` dictionary with the format `[Id:read]`. Read it when starting a new session and write in it the new updates statuses.

Save:

```
var notificationsStatus = ["101":true,"102":false]
let defaults:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(notificationsStatus, forKey: "notifications")
```

Read:

```
notificationsStatus = defaults.value(forKey: "notifications")
```

and then use the read/unread to color the cells accordingly

**Need to save the info for the same session**

Use some structure where you save the state of a notification. 
This can be done in multiple ways but the main idea is to create an object that doesn't get deallocated when leaving the controller and manipulate the date in it.

Comment: Yes, You are right. It will work only on the same device. I think I should add support for API to make it work on multiple device. Will be back if any difficulty after setting app the API. Thank you again.

Comment: My pleasure, anytime.